# Building Vite app with Vuefire gives me types error

Tags: typescript, vite, vuefire

I got a few errors durgin `vue-tsc` And cannot build the app with VueFire

```
node_modules/vuefire/dist/shared-6637dd22.d.ts:21:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

21     get data(): Ref<T>;
       ~~~

node_modules/vuefire/dist/shared-6637dd22.d.ts:21:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

21     get data(): Ref<T>;
           ~~~~

node_modules/vuefire/dist/shared-6637dd22.d.ts:21:15 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

21     get data(): Ref<T>;
                 ~

...
```

I'm trying to exclude the node_modules, but it does not work. I added excludes to the typescript config

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "3.3.14",
    "vue3-i18n": "1.1.4",
    "vuefire": "^3.1.8",
    "vuex": "4.0.2"
  },
```

vite config

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL || '';

export default defineConfig({
  base: BASE_URL,
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), vue()],
  build: {
    manifest: true
  },

});
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@enums/*": ["./src/enums/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["./src/interfaces/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./src/services/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Any ideas? Should I add exclude to the vite config, or maybe you have better idea why these errors occured?